# Content decryption using AES-128 cbc method through JavaScript

Tags: encryption, aes

I am working on a **ChromeApp**. In this App, we need to render some HTML, JPEG, PDF files. But all these files are encrypted using **AES-128-CBC** encryption method. We need to **decrypt** html, jpeg, png and pdf files using AES-128-CBC method through JavaScript. I have tried below code to decrypt but it does not give expected output:

```js
var ciphertext = '®0Ž.v£=p?°–æ£ËkRdKÓî¡¾”‹1Š"°?¥yAÈ_fëo e=Î} ú¿¯¢GE$iV×î’ÚÐøUJ²4Fœ‰=ÄQËÐ*R<Ã(ÕÎFÔ©—+Ùøä[„”Æ29ÿªSÆsi¬ôÓÆ@qÒÞãýñ?!ÉnÑZp²/öÇ~P‘/¿¡ç%í~Ô43]ÃÎG¾‹,+tPÜAàÛLkæ«œ‘É³f ç·ržúž´J›Ãá¥u®ÞFNœüÊöeL´Jîn<jí<ô¡ îÚY¥N6B•@¬˜krXyëÑtL<ú^ñ!±®¤–ÆœŸÌÉ£R¹ŒPþ*´¬/ú4´š7®´SóOgªr‹©;ï^îì­L5Ì©ãŽ£¡ØÏÞµð’Òyí`d~Lq<I€©|Ñ%ÚSâå½n.»5|zFÔR_ÀèbeYÌ‡Ç&Ù3ìÃ±jk¦®7';

function decryptPage()
{

 var originalKey = 'SuGpNMqP;md,(%F{';
 //var originalKey = '537547704e4d71503b6d642c2825467b';

 key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(originalKey);

 console.log(key);

 var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(ciphertext.slice(0, 32));
 
 var message = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({
     ciphertext: ciphertext
 }, key, {
     iv: iv
 });
 //console.log(hex2a(message.words));
 console.log('message');
 console.log(message.words);
}

decryptPage();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is?

Comment: You can start by writing some code. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Also, if the key is available in your Chrome App, what protection does it give to the content? Please read [Javascript Cryptography Considered Harmful](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/)

Comment: @EJoshuaS, Question is how to get HTML content from the encrypted files using JavaScript? Encryption is done using AES-128-CBC method. I have added key and some encrypted content. I don't have much idea about encryption. I am getting lot of reference in google but not getting any direct reference. I need help in this decryption work.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks for your suggestion. I think I have a good idea about Stack overflow forum and I know this is not a code writing service. I need a reference to get some idea about decryption of the HTML, JPEG files using AES-128-CBC method.

Comment: @SumantMishra I'm still confused as to exactly what your question is. Decrypting a HTML file is *exactly* the same as decrypting any other content. Is your question how to do decryption in general? Or do you have some decryption code already that's not working? If it's the first, there are plenty of tutorials out there on how AES and decryption in general works; if it's the second please post the code you've written. Also, the exact key you're using is irrelevant to the question. Either way, please edit your post to include a question, right now it's just statements.

Comment: @EJoshuaS, I have edited the question and added some code whatever I have tried so far. Hope, it helps you understand my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Can you also clarify what you mean by "does not give the expected output?" What output *does* it give and what were you expecting it to give instead? Also, one more quick point - in production code you'll obviously need a better way of storing and retrieving the key (as opposed to storing it in code like that).

Comment: Your ciphertext and key are not Hex-encoded, but your code suggests that they are. Generally, it's not possible to paste binary data such as a ciphertext or a key into a text file (JavaScript script file in this case). They always have to be encoded and Hex encoding is one viable way. Other than that, if the decrypted message is supposed to be a text message (HTML), then you need to decode that: `message.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)`

Answer (score 1):

As has already been pointed out in the comments, it's usually a bad idea to encrypt/decrypt in JavaScript.

With that said, decrypting these kinds of files is, in principal, exactly the same as decrypting other kinds of files.

In terms of cryptography itself, the basic idea of symmetric-key algorithms like AES is that items are encrypted and decrypted using the same key (there are separate methods available for making sure that both parties can securely exchange the key, generally relying on [public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography); see, for example, the [Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange)). Generally, decryption is more or less a reversal of the procedure used to encrypt in the first place.

The security of these algorithms rest in the secrecy of the key and the strength of the algorithm itself, *not* in the secrecy of the algorithm. So, for example, knowing the fact that you're encrypting and decrypting messages using AES is definitely *not* enough information for me to be able to recover the message content (unless I can also recover your key somehow, which is why it's important to store it in a secure manner, do all key exchanges securely, and rotate your keys periodically).

There are plenty of tutorials available on cryptography and encryption in general. For example, here's one below:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cryptography/
The Wikipedia articles on the topic are also pretty good.